# Как сделать скролл внутри меню с position fixed?

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, fixed, overflow

Создал фиксированное меню слева, которое выше высоты экрана.

Внутри меню хотел сделать скроллинг через `overflow`, но ничего не срабатывает:

```js
var gamb = document.querySelector('.gamb');
var minMenu = document.querySelector('.min-menu');
gamb.onclick = function() {
  minMenu.classList.add('show');
  gamb.classList.add('delete');
}
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.min-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.delete {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" class="gamb">gamb</button>
<div class="min-menu">
  <div class="links-min">
    <div class="link-min">
      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#main')" style="margin-left: 33px;">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#registrate')" style="margin-left: 21px;">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#aims')" style="margin-left: 24px;">Наши цели</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#start')" style="margin-left: 27px;">Как начать?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#pros')" style="margin-left: 31px;">Преимущества</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#why')" style="margin-left: 27px;">Почему мы?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#app')" style="margin-left: 22px;">Приложение</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#tarif')" style="margin-left: 20px;">Цены</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">

      <a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#contacts')" style="margin-left: 23px;">Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно что бы прокручивались "внутренности" Вашего меню, позиция которого при этом была бы фиксированой, поэтому я перенес scroll на один уровень ниже:

```js
const gamb = document.querySelector(".gamb")
const minMenu = document.querySelector(".min-menu")
gamb.onclick = () => {
  minMenu.classList.add("show")
  gamb.classList.add("delete")
}
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.min-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.links-min {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.delete {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" class="gamb">Показать меню</button>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="min-menu">
  <div class="links-min">
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Регистрация</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Наши цели</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Как начать?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Преимущества</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Почему мы?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Приложение</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Цены</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-min">
      <a>Мы в соцсетях</a>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код не работает когда основная часть сайта скроллинговая

Comment: @СаятУмаров все прекрасно работает, обновил ответ, что бы это показать